# What does args[0]['valid'] mean here in decorator

Tags: python, dictionary, decorator

`@authenticated` decorator allows the function to run is user1 has 'valid' set to `True`:

```
user1 = {
    'name': 'Sorna',
    'valid': False #changing this will either run or not run the message_friends function.
}

def authenticated(fn):
    def wrapper(*args , **kwargs):
        if args[0]['valid']:
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print(f'You are not authenticated to send messages. Please make deposit of $5 to your account')
    return wrapper


@authenticated
def message_friends(user):
    print('message has been sent')

message_friends(user1)
```

I am having troubles understanding why `args[0]['valid']` is used. When I used `args[1]['valid]` I got error,
I know i'm missing some key concept. please help me out here

Comment: `*args` is what is fed by your function call, in this case it's only `user1`, there is no `args[1]`

Comment: yes, user1 is args[0] (first and unique argument of your function)

Comment: `args` = the list of (positional) arguments, `args[0]` = the first argument…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **def wrapper(*args , **kwargs)** -> args represents the dictionary (user1), the if statement takes the dictionary (args[0]) and then takes the key 'valid' (args[0]['valid']), this way if the content of the key 'valid' is False you won't send the message (else statement) and if the content is True you will send the message.

Try changing the content of the valid key as follow:

```
user1 = {'name': 'Sorna','valid': True}
```

Under these circumstances, the message will be sent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now I understand

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck before on this one too, but I assume that should be the right answer:
**args** is passed to the function as tuple. In that case a tuple that has only one item (the user1 dictionary).

Something like this:
args = ({user1})

In order to access the key ['valid'], you need to indicate first that you are accessing the first item in the tuple **[0]**.

I expanded the code a bit: added another user and created for loop inside the authenticator to check throught the whole args tuple to check for the **['valid']** in as many users as you would like to input in the message function. It only returns the message if all the users have the 'valid' key set to True. If any item of the tuple args has the key set to False, the wrapper function returns None inside the if statement, not reaching the function to be called after the for loop

```
user1 = {'name': 'Sorna', 'valid': True}

user2 = {'name': 'Ivan', 'valid': True}

def authenticated(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(len(args)):
            if not args[i]['valid']:
                return None
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper



@authenticated
def message_friends(*args):
    print('message has been sent')

message_friends(user1, user2)
```